# Ubuntu cannot load desktop after RAM overload, even after restart

Tags: login, ram

I was running a Perl script, which used up all 8GB of RAM on my laptop (my fault, I know).  The computer was frozen, so I manually restarted with the power button.  I was then able to use Ubuntu, but it froze when connecting to WiFi.  Now when I restart, I enter my login credentials, Ubuntu acknowledges that I entered my username and password correctly, and then I get stuck in a blank screen.

edit: the control-alt-f1 and control-alt-F4 don't do anything either.

The Windows partition, however, still works.  Perhaps I can download something and alter a file somewhere?

I realize this is a very generic question, but I have absolutely no idea how to diagnose or fix this.  I've checked other pages with similar problems, but what they have doesn't apply to me because it is completely frozen.... no keyboard commands are available after I log in.  The mouse some times appears, but won't move.

EDIT: I can enter recovery mode, but I don't know what I can do with it.

Edit during restart, I get a stop job is running for Raise Network Interfaces, A stop job is running for WPA Supplicant.  This restart takes forever too.

how can I get my Ubuntu back?

Comment: I would try and login from a text terminal (ctl+alt+f4) and check for your naughty-script also chewing disk space or some other glitch (if disk space is too low you can't login to gui though it usually returns you to login); eg. `ls -ltrha` or look for changes/additions, even unwanted removals..

Comment: If you type "`blank screen after login`" into the AskUbuntu Search box (https://askubuntu.com/search?q=blank+screen+after+login ) you'll see 371 questions about similar problems, some with answers. Some of these 371 may be useful.

Comment: I'd boot from live usb first to make sure that still works OK.